# Get the latest file in directories taking a long to run

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, io

I have this code that finds the latest zip file in directories. The program runs pretty fast with few folders but with many folders, like 789 folders that I need to look into, that have zip files in them, the code takes more than 30 mins to produce the output. Any tips on how I can make this code run faster?

```
import os, glob

cwd = os.getcwd()

list_of_latest = []
for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk(cwd):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.zip'):
            list_of_files = glob.glob(dirname + '\*.zip')
            latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime) 
            if latest_file not in list_of_latest:
                list_of_latest.append(latest_file)

for i in list_of_latest:
    print i
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: perhaps you could spawn processes to do this in parallel, I don't know what will make it go from 30 minutes to a few seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not have realised it, but there is a redundant loop in your code. This piece of code here:

```
for filename in files:
    if filename.endswith('.zip'):
        list_of_files = glob.glob(dirname + '\*.zip')
```

The `glob.glob` will retrieve *all* zip files in the present directory (specified by `dirname` which is the root path. Now, if you have 10 `zip` files in that directory, you will run `glob.glob` 10 times! And each time, you find the same file. But it is appended to the list only the first.

That entire inner loop can be simplified to something like this:

```
for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk(cwd):
    list_of_files = glob.glob(dirname + '\*.zip')
    if len(list_of_files) == 0: 
        continue
    latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime) 

    if latest_file not in list_of_latest:
        list_of_latest.append(latest_file)
```

That inner loop is unnecessary.

Comment: I tried this. It's giving me a valueError saying: max() arg is an empty sequence. @Coldspeed

Comment: @JeanPaulMugisha Try it now? I've added an if check.

Comment: @JeanPaulMugisha No problems. If this answer helped you, do consider accepting it. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over all files in a directory **twice** - once with:

```
for filename in files:
```

and then:

```
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
```

What you probably want is:

```
for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk(cwd):
    list_of_files = glob.glob(dirname + '\*.zip')
    latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime) 
    if latest_file not in list_of_latest:
        list_of_latest.append(latest_file)
```

Oh, and if you used a set instead of a list for `list_of_latest` it would allow for further simplification:

```
list_of_latest = set()
for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk(cwd):
    list_of_files = glob.glob(dirname + '\*.zip')
    latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime) 
    list_of_latest.add(latest_file)
```

Comment: I tried this but it's throwing an ValueError saying: max() arg is an empty sequence @Blotosmetek